# Best way to create a MySQL database? Tables or separate databases?

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

Hopefully someone can answer this fairly straightforward question I have. I've just started using MySQL & phpMyAdmin for creating a backend database for a server, I'm trying to figure out the best way to create a database index for that server. The main database will hold the following tables; music, videos, doc's & files. 
The (music) section will hold (5) tables. 
The (videos) section will hold (4) tables. 
The (doc & files) will hold around (5) tables.

My question is the following; What would be better, separate databases for each of the above, or should I just put those 14 tables within the main index database?

My other question is, Can I create a index database which would include (FK)'s to all the other tables to use for querying & file searching?

Any info would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In my opinión is better to have all together and name them with a prefix. as

```
video_table1
video_table2
....
```

That way you are not making connections to other dbs.
My answer is applied only if all tables are for the same application, otherwise do separate dbs

```
Can I create a index database which would include (FK)'s to all the other tables to use for querying & file searching?
```

If you're using InnoDB. YES!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Hansel! Yes I'm using InnoDB

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have foreign key relationships between two tables, you should put both tables in the same database. Basically, all the contents of a single ERD (entity-relationship diagram) should be kept in the same database.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit skeptical about your setup, but I'd need more details.  As for your specific question about multiple databases vs. a single database, other than some possible size limitations on very large databases I don't think there is actually any difference.  That is, choose whatever works best for you.  You may prefer the organization of multiple databases, or you might like to keep them in one.  If you use multiple databases you will not be able to do database-wide operations on all the tables at once (`DROP DATABASE`, `mysqldump` with tables).  Foreign keys can exist across databases.

As for your question about the "index database," I'm not entirely sure I understand and it probably depends.  You could have a `Files` table with foreign keys to file types (videos, music) and make your database more generalized.

Comment: A rough breakdown of the index table

Comment: A rough breakdown of the index table; genreID (FK) -> music_genre table; songID (FK)-> songs table;  videoID (FK) -> video table; docID (FK)-> doc_file table. Each of these (FK)'s will also be listed within each of the corresponding tables. I hope this makes sense in this format, iPads & carriage returns don't mix we'll with this comment section. Also, all of my tables will include at least 2x FK's linked to the "index table". Will this work? Thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends a lot on what do you actually need for your project. Will the sections ever interact with one another (for example, does a music can be releated to a video?)?

If the answer is YES -> Use a single database for all the tables;
If the answer is NO -> You can have separate databases for each "section";

Answer (score 0):

If the target is:

1. a single app,
2. you want to do work combining data from all these tables and
3. you do not anticipate breaking these out in to separate applications deployed in separate environments:

A single database is fine / likely best. If the answer to any of the above questions is no, then you may still want a single database, but more work may be needed.

On your second question, the structure for how you map your (objects?) to the database depends on how you will be using them and somewhat on the language and (more importantly - the frameworks) you intend to use to develop your application. If you are looking to model these in your application as different types of a super-class `file` you may want to look at the different object oriented approaches to how to structure your tables (e.g. [Table-per-type, table-per-hierarchy](http://blogs.devart.com/dotconnect/table-per-type-vs-table-per-hierarchy-inheritance.html)).

For example, common fields could be in a base table `Files` and type specific data could be in the table `AudioFiles`. The primary key for `AudioFiles` would be a foreign key to `Files`